# Bad value for type int : auditel. Solution?

Tags: java, jdbc

I execute my code and the compiler give me this error. "Eccezione instanziazione 1 f.getGroup().add()Bad value for type int : auditel." Someone knows how to solve this problem? I search in internet and I try some solutions but appear always the same problem. Here is the part of that doesn't run:

```
for(Famiglia f: family) {
            try(PreparedStatement pst_G = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id, epg_channel_id, user, startime, endtime FROM log2_3min_groups_clean WHERE family_id = ?")) {
                //set the variables
                pst_G.setInt(1, f.getId()); //parameters are: (index <of var>, value <of var>)
                //eseguo la query
                ResultSet rs_G = pst_G.executeQuery();
                //foreach record from the database about every action of every family's component
                //int indexGroup = 0;
                //int indexUserIntoGroup = 0; attualmente non in uso
                while(rs_G.next()) {
                    //se la lista è vuota
                    if(f.getGroup().isEmpty()){
                        //instanzio il primo gruppo e utente

                        //stringa data and ora
                        String dataOraStart = rs_G.getString("starttime"); //format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ms:ss'
                        String dataOraFine = rs_G.getString("endtime"); //format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ms:ss'

                        try {

                            //ottengo data inizio dalla stringa
                            int yyS = Integer.parseInt(dataOraStart.substring(0,4));
                            int mmS = Integer.parseInt(dataOraStart.substring(5,7));
                            int ddS = Integer.parseInt(dataOraStart.substring(8,10));
                            //quindi, LocalDate
                            LocalDate dS = LocalDate.of(yyS, mmS, ddS);

                            //ottengo ora inizio dalla stringa
                            int hhS = Integer.parseInt(dataOraStart.substring(11,13));
                            int msS = Integer.parseInt(dataOraStart.substring(14,16));
                            int ssS = Integer.parseInt(dataOraStart.substring(17,19));
                            //quindi, LocalTime
                            LocalTime hS = LocalTime.of(hhS, msS, ssS);

                            //ottengo data di fine dalla stringa
                            int yyE = Integer.parseInt(dataOraFine.substring(0,4));
                            int mmE = Integer.parseInt(dataOraFine.substring(5,7));
                            int ddE = Integer.parseInt(dataOraFine.substring(8,10));
                            //quindi, LocalDate
                            LocalDate dE = LocalDate.of(yyE, mmE, ddE);

                            //ottengo ora di fine dalla stringa
                            int hhE = Integer.parseInt(dataOraFine.substring(11,13));
                            int msE = Integer.parseInt(dataOraFine.substring(14,16));
                            int ssE = Integer.parseInt(dataOraFine.substring(17,19));
                            //quindi, LocalTime
                            LocalTime hE = LocalTime.of(hhE, msE, ssE);

                            try {

                                f.getGroup().add(new Gruppo(rs_G.getInt("epg_channel_id"),  dS, hS, dE, hE));

                                for(int idx = 0; idx < utenti.size(); idx++)
                                    if(utenti.get(idx).getId() == rs_G.getInt("current_user"))
                                        idxUtente = idx;

                                if(f.getGroup().get(0).addUtente(utenti.get(idxUtente), rs_G.getInt("epg_channel_id"), dS, hS, dE, hE, rs_G.getInt("id")) == true) { //get(0) it's better than others 'cause if we know the list it's empty and also we use add() method, we know there is only one element at the index=0
                                    System.out.println("Expected");
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Unexpected");
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Eccezione instanziazione 1 f.getGroup().add()" + e.getMessage());
                            }
```

Comment: I don't see the word `auditel` in the code or the query anywhere. does it have a special meaning in italian?

Comment: What data type is the column `starttime`? If that is a `date` or `timestamp` you should retrieve the value using `rs_G.getObject("starttime", LocalDate.class)`  or `rs_G.getObject("starttime", LocalDateTime.class)` rather than trying to parse a string. If it's not a `date` or `timestamp` then you should fix your data model. **Never** store date/time values in `varchar` columns.

Comment: Also, your error message (that *you* defined) assumes that only a problem with `f.getGroup().add()` will throw an exception.  But you're catching any exception in a quite large portion of code. At least while debugging, you should also print a stack trace to understand *where* in that bunch of code the exception is being thrown.

Comment: @f1sh that's the Italian equivalent of Nielsen ratings, but that's not so relevant to the question, as it's data that comes from the db. The important thing is: it's not a number.

Comment: Generally speaking, you solve this problem by not trying to parse something that's not a number. `auditel` is not a number, unless you're using "base-31" numeral system. In latter case, you supply a proper redix to the code that's going to parse your numbers.

Comment: Auditel is the name of the database. 
Starttime is a timestamp but I try to use rs_G.getTimestamp and give me an error.

Comment: I would guess the error is in `rs_G.getInt("current_user")`.  `current_user` isn't one of the columns you are returning in your query - perhaps you meant `rs_G.getInt("user")` instead?   It looks like whatever database you are using is interpreting `current_user` as the user you are logged in to the database as.

Comment: No it's correct current_user, before I wrote user but it was an error because the name that appear in database is user but the correct name is current_user